# SQL Server: select count of rows with not empty fields and total count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table has 4 int columns (Price0, Price1, Price2, Price3).

Example of table:

```
ID | Price0 | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 |
---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
 1 |   10   |   20   |  NULL  |  NULL  |
 2 |   70   |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
 3 |   30   |   40   |   50   |  NULL  |
```

How to query this table to get

1. total count of rows
2. and count of rows where count of filled Price columns >= N (for example N = 2)

Result must be:

```
Total | Filled
------+-------
  3   |   2
```

This query show how many Price fileds is filled in each row

```
select
    (select count(*) as filledFieldsCount
     from (values (T.Price0), (T.Price1), (T.Price2), (T.Price3)) as v(col)
     where v.col is not null
    )
from Table1 T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't with only 4 columns a simple nested case when be straightforward

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when (
                CASE WHEN Price1 is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
                CASE WHEN Price2 is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
               CASE WHEN Price3 is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
               CASE WHEN Price4 is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when tt.filledFieldsCount >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
from Table1 T outer apply
     (select count(*) as filledFieldsCount
      from (values (T.Price0), (T.Price1), (T.Price2), (T.Price3)) as v(col)
      where v.col is not null
     ) tt;
```

I moved the subquery to the `from` clause using `apply`.  This is an example of a *lateral join*.  In this case, it does the same thing as the subquery.

Comment: Would it be a little cleaner to use `COUNT(v.col)` and remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . This is the OP's original code.  I actually think it is pretty clear and simpler than a massive expression with a bunch of `case` expressions.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `CASE` expressions, just `COUNT(field)` vs `COUNT(*) WHERE field IS NOT NULL` ;)